# Does dagrun_timeout interfere when backfilling / clearing old DAGs?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG like below, with `dagrun_timeout` set to 4 hours. When I go to the UI and clear all the tasks from the start_date to present, all DAGs are set to the running state.

After 4 hours, any DAG that has not marked itself as successful will be marked failed, even if they have not actually started yet. I am wondering whether this is intended behavior.

Should I remove the `dagrun_timeout` and put timeouts on the task level, if I want to rerun DAGs in this fashion? Or should I use `airflow backfill` instead if I want to rerun all DAGs without the `dagrun_timeout` interfering?

Ideally I'd like to be able to use the UI since other team members will want to rerun DAGs.

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 5, 1),
    'email': ['lol@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=8,
    schedule_interval='15 * * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60*4),
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's intended behavior, but just a misleading parameter name. It has been discussed on the mailing list before, see https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/7bda30f518bedbaaa763ba73a5e3bbe386cb0d090834c819f81c65ec@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E.

Moving the timeout to the task level is a fair alternative, just understand it will be a little different since you'd probably want to determine a reasonable timeout per task. If it's critical that you are alerted if DAG runs take longer than 4 hours in the ordinary (non-backfill) scenario, then I'd add 4 hour SLAs on all the tasks. When you clear tasks for backfill, it will immediately trigger the SLA misses, but at least they should all happen at once in bulk and won't fail your runs.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck into the same problem. Just remove the `dagrun_timeout` parameter. Re-run task wiil be run normally.